# Naming variable for median calculation using Numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, median

I'm using numpy to get the median. The dataframe has two variables. Is there a way to tell it which variable I want the median for?

np.median(dataframename)

Comment: why not using pandas median ?

Answer (score 0):

You must make cast your dataframe to numpy vector. Try this:

```
#input data in dataframename
dataframename = np.asarray(dataframename)
dataframename = dataframename.astype(float)
np.median(dataframename)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is one of the fields Identifying the variable I want to analyze. it just uses the first column. I want to use the second column - maybe call it var2

Comment: you can to use index, eg. `np.median(dataframename[index])` where index is 0 - size of dataframename. In your case, `np.median(dataframename[1])`

Comment: Thanks! I get the same answer. it calculates on the first column instead of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my data was not in a dataframe. Once I put it in, this worked. 
dataframename.loc[:,"var18"].median()